# Android: wifi p2p disabling event (not disabled)

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I register a receiver for the action

```
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION
```

In `onReceive()` I get this action and compare the `EXTRA_WIFI_STATE` to this two cases

```
    case WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED:

    case WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_DISABLED:
```

However I need to know when Wifi is going to be disabled but not disabled yet, in order to call some methods of the WifiP2pManager. I have to call

```
  manager.clearLocalServices
```

before wifi is disabled, otherwise it fails and the service is not removed.
How can I get the "disabling" event?

Comment: I made the observation, that the service is removed when wifi gets disabled.

Comment: why other nearby devices can still see it?

Comment: If I clear the service when wifi is enabled, the others stop to see it. This is why I have to intercept the "disabling" event

Comment: There is an event WIFI_STATE_DISABLING, which you could use. Unfortunately this will fail with the "BUSY" error as well. So other devices see the services when you disable and enable the wifi?

Comment: Each service is announced individually. So there are no lists and you can't compare the new list with a previouse one. Unfortunately Disabling is also a BUSY condition for the p2p framework

Comment: the only way is to register for peer list change (not services) and check the list of device. All this because they don't give you a list of services (but they do for devices)

Comment: Sorry, I lost you now. What do you mean with list of services and list of devices? Maybe edit your question and elaborate a bit more what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding here. Most apps that use Wifi Direct search for peers and maintain a list of available peers.

However, you will often find that implementations do not remove peers when they are no longer available. When WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_DISABLED, then by definition, the device is no longer available to other peers. So any peers that think that the device is still available probably just haven't updated the list of "available" peers, that is, they haven't checked which devices are still available.

To verify what the behavior truly is, you should try searching for the device  AFTER the state has changed to WIFI_P2P_STATE_DISABLED. If peers are still able to find your device after this event, then there is a fundamental bug in the Android implementation, which I doubt.